# Нестандартная сортировка подсчётом Java

Tags: java, алгоритм, сортировка

### Задача выглядит следующим образом :

Необходимо найти число, которое встречается в этой последовательности наибольшее количество раз,
а если таких чисел несколько, то найти минимальное из них,
и после этого переместить все такие числа в конец заданной последовательности.
Порядок расположения остальных чисел должен остаться без изменения.

---

```
 * 1
 * 2
 * 3  
 * 2 
 * 3
 * 1
 * 2
```

Превращается в :

```
 * 1
 * 3
 * 3
 * 1
 * 2
 * 2
 * 2
```

Причём данные нужно прочитать из файла и записать отсортированный массив тоже в файл
Я попробовал решить её путём создания ТриМэпа, в котором ведется подсчёт повторений, затем пройти этот Мэп, чтобы определить необходимое число, которое повтовторяется в последовательности чаще всего и количество его повторений.
А затем выводить массив без этого числа, добавить его только циклом в конце.

Собственно сам вопрос, как по мне получилось очень громоздко, я уверен, что есть более элегантное решение. Но не могу сам додуматься какое? Помогите, пожалуйста

```
static public void sortSequence(String inputName, String outputName) throws IOException {

    try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputName), "UTF-8"));
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputName), "UTF-8"))) {

        String line;
        ArrayList<Integer> originArray = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            originArray.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
        }

        Map<Integer, Integer> countOfNumbers = new TreeMap<>();

        for (Integer num : originArray) {
            if (countOfNumbers.containsKey(num)) {
                countOfNumbers.put(num, countOfNumbers.get(num) + 1);
            } else {
                countOfNumbers.put(num, 1);
            }
        }

        Integer valueOfMax = 0;
        int countOfMax = 0;

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> pair : countOfNumbers.entrySet()) {
            if (pair.getValue() > countOfMax) {
                countOfMax = pair.getValue();
                valueOfMax = pair.getKey();
            }
        }

        for (Integer number : originArray) {
            if (!number.equals(valueOfMax)) {
                bufferedWriter.write(number.toString());
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
                bufferedWriter.flush();
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }

        while (countOfMax > 0) {
            bufferedWriter.write(valueOfMax.toString());
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            countOfMax--;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Какой разбег у чисел? Это всегда числа 1-3?

Comment: также не понял, где у вас `а если таких чисел несколько, то найти минимальное из них`?

Comment: @tym32167 от 0 до 100000 в тестах

Comment: а количество чисел всего сколько?

Comment: @tym32167 точное кол-во не обговорено, но я так понял может быть очень большим, вплоть до миллиона

Comment: @tym32167 что касается минимального, то постарался реализовать это в данном куске        `for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> pair : countOfNumbers.entrySet()) {
            if (pair.getValue() > countOfMax) {
                countOfMax = pair.getValue();
                valueOfMax = pair.getKey();
            }
        }                                                                                                                                                      
`

Comment: ну, миллион это немного. Я просто подумал, что вместо treemap можно было бы использовать обычный массив на 100к элементов. Но а в целом ничего преступного в вашем коде не вижу. Разве что я бы не стал использовать TreeMap, так как при работе с ним ключи сортируются, то есть каждая вставка вам стоит log(n), а вам не надо сортировать ключи, вам надо один раз по ним пробежать и минимум найти, а это линейная операция. Вам тут по сути вообще ничего сортировать не надо.

Comment: @tym32167 Тут идёт проход по мапу, и если число такое же по количеству повторений, но больше по значению, то оно не пройдёт за счёт строгого знака '>'

Comment: @tym32167 Хорошо, понял вас) Сейчас переделаю под обычный массив, согласен, тримап тут видимо излишен. Спасибо большое)

Comment: Есть вариант просто отсортировать. Тогда сложность будет O(n log n), а по памяти выйдет O(n)

Comment: @АртёмВикторович вам необязвтельно даже массив брать, вы можете обычный хешмап взять, который не сортирует, у него операции константные

Comment: @Miron тут сортировка не нужна особо, можно обойтись линейной памятью и линейным временем. O(n log n) - это то, что автор имеет сейчас.

Comment: @tym32167 в реальной жизни такое не прокатит(если не будет ограничений, конечно). Думаю, что в голове у автора было именно такое решение - сортировка

Comment: @Miron про реальную жизнь не понял. Ведь после сортировки все равно надо будет делать подсчет, так тогда смысл сортировки? Я использовал подсчет и в реальной жизни, и на SO давал ответы с ним, полет нормальный.

Comment: @tym32167 не придется. Так вам достаточно иметь всего четыре переменные - самоеЧастоеЧисло, сколькоОноВстретилось, сколькоВстретилосьТекущееЧисло и текущееЧисло. А так это потому, что одинаковые числа после сортировки идут друг за другом - и никак иначе.

Comment: А так вы задействуете массив размерностью в весь алфавит

Comment: @Miron ну то есть вы предлагаете копировать весь массив - O(n) дополнительной памяти (мы не можем менять исходный массив, порядок исходных данных надо сохранить для вывода), копию сортировать за NlogN и потом ещё за N сделать обход. Я предлагаю использовать массив (100k элементов) или хешмап (O(n) памяти), и за линейное время сделать подсчет. В чем преимущество вашего подхода?

Comment: @tym32167 В данном случае при совершенно формальном ограничении алфавита в 100к ваш способ действительно отработает лучше. Но если этого ограничения не будет(или будет, но в 10^9, например), ваш способ вообще не сработает. Я считаю, что это вредный подход к решению задачи.

Comment: @Miron вы говорите про алфавит, я понял. Я сам не знаю требований автора, потому дал ему выбор - массив или хешмап. Оба варианта примерно одинаковы по времени и очень просто переделать из одного в другое  и наоборот.

Comment: Еще одна подсказка - не надо делать `bufferedWriter.flush();` каждый раз, его надо делать 1 раз в конце метода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе алгоритм не отличается, просто немного приправлено java 8

```
static public void sortSequence(String inputName, String outputName) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
         BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        List<Integer> originArray = bufferedReader.lines().map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
        transform(originArray).forEach(number -> {
            try {
                bufferedWriter.write(number.toString());
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
            }
        });
    }
}

static public Stream<Integer> transform(List<Integer> originArray) {
    Map<Integer, Long> cntMap = originArray.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
    Map.Entry<Integer, Long> max = Collections.max(cntMap.entrySet(),
            Map.Entry.<Integer, Long>comparingByValue() // максимум по value
                    .thenComparing(Map.Entry.<Integer, Long>comparingByKey().reversed()) // минимум по key
    );
    return Stream.concat(
            originArray.stream().filter(x -> !x.equals(max.getKey())),
            Stream.generate(max::getKey).limit(max.getValue())
    );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Смотрю на это как на мотивацию) Со стримами еще на Вы пока что, конечно. Может расскажите, как вы их изучали? Что-то по типу "Современного языка java" или не по книгам, а просто статьи в интернете?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ такой предложу.

Первые два цикла можно объединить. Считать количество все равно придется. В третьем цикле вы не учитываете равенство countOfMax и выбор наименьшего. А по остальному я проблем не вижу.

Comment: `В третьем цикле вы не учитываете равенство countOfMax и выбор наименьшего` - `TreeMap<>` сортированный, потому это учитывается.

Comment: Артем, так я смотрю на Map, и сортировка не нужна так как он все равно перебирает все ключи

Comment: сортировка только помогает выбрать наименьший ключ с наибольшим количеством повторений. Что сортировка не нужна уже написано в комментах :)

Comment: А я и не спорю по сортировке, говорю что не нужна и нужно проверить на равенство

Comment: я тож не спорю, только говорю, что это уже все есть в комментах. Но не вижу проблем добавить это в твой ответ. Заодно можешь и к `bufferedWriter.flush();` приглядеться :)

Comment: Предложил объединить два цикла к вашим комментариям

Comment: Болтаем мы с тобой Артем ни о чем вот ответ человек написал в StreamApi старался

Comment: Ну у него тоже минус - делает лишнюю копию массива в конце. Если уже юзать стрим, то его и возвращать тогда, чтобы не тратить память лишнюю.